# Flask and Postgresql - sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input value for enum

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is the model

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql


class MyModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mytables'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    option = db.Column(postgresql.ENUM('YES', 'NO', 'MAYBE', name='_option', create_type=False), nullable=False)
    data = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

This is the class I use to store the data

```
class myList(Resource):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

    def post(self):
        data = myList.parser.parse_args()

        my_json = request.get_json()
        my_data = my_schema.load(my_json)

        my_data.save()

        return my_schema.dump(my_data), 201
```

This is my schema

```
from ma import ma
from models.mymodel import MyModel

class MySchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = True
```

And this is the complete error message, assuming I give YES input

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input value for enum status_option: ""YES""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution

so below the model table I put on the question, I have this method

```
def __init__(self, datetime, option, data):
    self.datetime = datetime
    self.option = json.dumps(option)
    self.data = data
```

then I changed it into this and its working

```
def __init__(self, datetime, option, data):
    self.datetime = datetime
    self.option = option
    self.data = data
```